# Can any area of math come into play in Machine Learning Research?

Tags: machine-learning, math, research

As I read online following areas in mathematics come into play in ML research

- Linear Algebra
- Calculus
- Differential Equations
- Probability
- Statistics
- Discrete Mathematics
- Optimization
- Analytic Geometry
- Topology
- Numerical and Real Analysis

Can / Are any other areas of math used in ML research? If so what other areas? ex: Number theory

Comment: Probably not number theory, except for combinatorics.

Comment: Convex geometry, can it be?

Comment: [Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/7352/2444) is a related question.